# Windows Mobile 6.5 flick (scrolling with inertia) not working

Tags: visual-c++, windows-mobile, listview, gesture-recognition, gesture

After upgrading to windows mobile 6.5, my ListView control does not work properly with custom items (rows with alternate colors) and the new gesture mechanism... On a mobile device, if the user initiates a flick or pan, after scrolling the first few items, the last items are not shown on the screen, but will show up if the user explicitly taps on them -- so basically the last screen is just white. The WM_DRAWITEM message is sent to all children though, but they just don't show up on the screen. Scrolling with a bar works fine.

Any ideas?

I have seen some reports of similar behavior from other users, but not sure if this is a bug in the listview control itself or if there is something else that needs to/can be implemented to support flick and pan actions. The application code currently doesn't handle WM_GESTURE messages, so the flick action is done with Microsoft's own code to support legacy applications.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution -- this was an internal issue...